# Waiting for data from server .net Tcp

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, tcp

I have Tcp Client-Server application. Client write data to stream, and wait for data from server.

But server doing work near 10-15 seconds, so how would better for client to wait data from server? Put some "waiter" method in background thread or to sleep client for some time?

Client:

```
 client.Connect(ip, serverPort);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(user.GetType());
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, user);
                    Thread.Sleep(250);
                    //WaitSignal(client);
                }
```

Server:

```
         TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, serverPort);
         string msg = "Hello;"
         listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wait...");
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
                 {
                  //read bytes from stream and do some work

                   byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                   stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                 }
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `async` version of methods like [NetworkStream.WriteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.writeasync?view=netcore-3.1)? It's an optimized way to wait for asynchronous operation to finish.

Comment: @cassandrad but when client recieve data in async way it will read all stream earlier, then server will recieve stream

Comment: What do you mean?